# There is a (social) network / website for developers share ideas and find a team for development?

Tags: team, teamwork, websites, social-networks

Supposing I want to do some kind of project, but I want to find more people interested in that area that can develop some project with me, there is some website focused on this?

Example: "I want to develop action games for mobiles" or "Want to find web developers for a new social network focused on blah blah blah".

This already exists?

Comment: I think there is, but I can't recall the name.  I'm hoping someone else remembers it

Comment: Isn't StackOverflow and Programmers SE enough ? :P

Comment: @dysoco Ha! ... Try posting a question about a project you want to develop and looking for interested developers and see how fast you get closed and how many downvotes you get. If there is one thing SO is not, it's tolerant. (But that is not necessarily a bad thing)

Comment: Hi Renato Dinhani Conceição, recommendation lists are [off-topic here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @Mark Trapp I don't asking about who is the best. I want to know if exists: "Yes, exists, this site: ..." or "No, don't exists". This is because I searched and never found something like this.

Comment: Anywhere programmers hang out you can post if they let you or get in a chat. No one is going to qualify candidates.

Comment: I Actually think this is a good and valid question... He is not asking for opinions on sites, he is asking for the existance of one. The answer is not subjective, and I for one would also like to know if such a site exists, since I would as well be interested in it. The question does not precisely fit into any of the allowed criteria, but it does not fit into the violation criteria either... I think you were too quick to dismiss it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/).

> Learn what people are using and contributing to. See what's going on
>   inside an open source project. Follow what your friends are coding

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, check out [Github](https://github.com/) ... It a version control system but with a social factor and a developer community.

Check out the community features of github: https://github.com/features/community

Comment: I love Github and use it for my projects, but IMO Github isn't really meant for gaging interest on an idea unless you're prepared to start coding said idea without any initial feedback.